# WildFly cannot start GeoServer 2.16.2

Tags: geoserver, jboss

I am running successfully GeoServer 2.15.0 as a Web Archive started from WildFly 16.0.0 using OpenJDK 1.8.0 (RPM built for CentOS 7.6).

I would like to upgrade to GeoServer 2.16.2 (i.e. the latest stable release as of today) but the service cannot be started.

Here is the first error shown:

```
2020-02-13 11:27:14,554 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."geoserver.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."geoserver.war".component."org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module "deployment.geoserver.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        ... 33 more
```

I would say that the key problem here is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` but I do not know how to fix it.

There are several identical issues ; here is the full list:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor (Module "deployment.geoserver.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerWriteProcessor (Module "deployment.geoserver.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestBodyPublisher (Module "deployment.geoserver.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerReadPublisher (Module "deployment.geoserver.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module "deployment.geoserver.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber
```

I have removed all GeoServer plugins and community modules in order to minimize side effects.

I should mention that GeoServer runs fine under Jetty instead of WildFly.

I also have upgraded WildFly from 16.0.0 to 18.0.1, but the service still does not start. I also upgraded OpenJDK from 1.8.0 to 11.0.6, still the same. And of course I have tested each combination (WF16+Java8, WF16+Java11, WF18+Java8, WF18+Java11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question because I finally found how to fix the issue.

While loading the GeoServer 2.16 Web Archive, WildFly is in need of [reactive-streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/). It is unclear why this dependency occurred with GeoServer 2.16 this but definitely appeared with 2.16 and onward (tested with 2.16.0, 2.16.2 and master (2.17)).

I should mention the problem is very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709747/update-to-spring-5-1-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-http).

### Quick fix

The fastest way to solve this problem consists in copying the reactive-streams JAR to the WEB-INF directory, i.e.:

1. unzip the GeoServer WAR in the deployments directory of WildFly, e.g. if the deployments dir is `/path/to/deployments` then create a directory `/path/to/deployments/geoserver.war/` and copy the contents of the unzipped geoserver.war into this folder
2. download the reactive-streams JAR, e.g. [1.0.3 from the Maven Repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar)
3. copy `reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar` to `/path/to/deployments/geoserver.war/WEB-INF/lib/`
4. tell WildFly to deploy the server by creating the `.dodeploy` file, e.g. `touch /path/to/deployments/geoserver.war.dodeploy`

### The hard way

The other option requires building GeoServer by yourself.

I chose Maven but you may want to take a look [at other options](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/quickstart/index.html).

1. download the [zipped source code package for tag 2.16.2](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/archive/2.16.2.zip) and unzip it locally
2. add the following dependency in `src/pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

3. add the following dependency in `src/main/pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

4. build the project with Maven:

`mvn -DskipTests -T 2C clean install`

If everything goes well, a WAR file is created at this location `src/web/app/target/geoserver.war`

You can check if reactive-streams is included in the WAR by calling:

`jar tf geoserver.war WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: I filed an issue at osgeo for geoserver regarding this problem.